# Using the shell, how to determine percentage of torrent file downloaded?

Tags: bash, shell, linux-mint, terminal, bittorrent

I am busy downloading files over Deluge and would like to know how to check the percentages of the files downloaded, using the Terminal.

Ideally, I would like to be able to check individual files as I have HUGE collections in Deluge and finding the individual files are cumbersome.

Comment: Do you actually mean "Using the shell, how to determine.... ?" ?

Comment: Yes, using shell / terminal / command line / bash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks possible but comes with a list of prerequisites. You'll need :

- the full list of files you're downloading. Each entry must be the exact file name, as it'll appear on your computer once the download is done. They sometimes have long and complex names like  "title.of.whatever.-.Name.of.Release.team.-.2019.-.....fileextension"
- the full size of each file, ideally in bytes so that your final percentage will be more accurate
- the pattern used to name partially downloaded files. Usually appending a ".part" to the file name

Once you have this, build a CSV-like file formatted like :
`fileName,sizeInBytes`

Then a script that will :

1. read your list line by line
2. extract the data fields : fileName, file size
3. compute the "temp" file name, something like "$fileName.part"
4. get its size in bytes with `ls -l` or `stat` + `grep` / `cut` / `awk`
5. compute the achieved percentage

You'll find plenty of help and examples on StackExchange ;-)

Comment: I really am looking for a short, single line, format using the shell - IF there is any...